# How to style javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to style alert message screen in javascript.

I've been testing almost all kinds of methods to style alert message screen

by using alertify.js , sweetalert.js, dialog etc.

However, these mothods couldn't stop whole system. As you know, javascript

alert has function that stopping whole codes until 'ok' button will be clicked.

all methods that i had tried above didn't provide that stopping function.

What methods should i have to use?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to post what code you have tried so far and explain where the issue is.

Comment: There is no particular codes.

I just asked about other functions that provides similar functions like

'pure' alert.

Comment: So you need to show what you have attempted.  You waste people's time posting answers that you have already tried.

Comment: The `alert()`method opens a dialog box controlled by your browser. it HAS to be in the design of the browser. imagine if someone could style it to be a windows dialog or something else. horrible thoughts occur. Sounds like you ought to recode your app to not use `alert()`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is not possible. You cannot style the native javascript alert, and any non-native solution won't behave the exact same way as the native alert does.

The best you can do is make some alert UI (using html/css and a bit of js to toggle it on/off) that overlays the page (using css and a higher zindex most likely) and prevents the user from interacting with the content underneath.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.

I tried similar method that you mentioned while following this video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RLE2Q7OzME

this source blocked whole page but it restarts whole page again..

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 includes an element called `dialog`, which unlike JavaScript's `alert(text)`, can be styled.

```js
function opendialog() {
  const element = document.getElementById("foo"); // Your element ID here
  element.open = true;
  console.log("Dialog opened");
}

function closedialog() {
  const element = document.getElementById("foo"); // Your element ID here
  element.open = false;
  console.log("Dialog closed");
}
```

```css
/*I am the dev of this style https://github.com/TylerMS887/adwaita.css*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cantarell&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Red+Hat+Mono&display=swap');
code,
pre {
  font-family: monospace, "Red Hat Mono";
}

select {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  select {
    background-color: #5B5B5B;
    color: white;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", system-ui, sans-serif;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  dialog {
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px darkgray;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    background-color: #3A3A3A;
    color: white;
  }
}

button {
  transition: background-color 0.5s, color 0.5s;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  button {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", system-ui, sans-serif;
  }
  button:hover {
    background-color: #b0b0b0;
  }
  button:active {
    background-color: #828282;
  }
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  button {
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 7.5px;
    background-color: #5B5B5B;
    color: white;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", system-ui, sans-serif;
  }
  button:hover {
    background-color: #3F3F3F;
  }
  button:active {
    background-color: #2D2D2D;
  }
}

dialog {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
  transition: background-color 0.5s, box-shadow 0.5s;
  color 0.5s;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 8px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom-color: #66afe9;
}

.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: background-color 0.05s;
}

.container:hover input~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.container input:disabled~.checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.05s;
}

.container input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  opacity: 100;
}

.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  border-radius: 1.5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

kbd {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", system-ui, sans-serif;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  kbd {
    background-color: #5B5B5B;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="opendialog()">Open the dialog</button>
<dialog id="foo">
  <b>Hello World</b>
  <p>This dialog opened on run-time!</p>
  <br>
  <div class="dialog-buttons"><button onclick="closedialog()">Close dialog</button></div>
</dialog>
```